# Rigid Bodies with Follow Path Constraint

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I am creating a scene in which an object with rigid body type active is following a path (constraint).

[image: Project_ss]

I wanted to test it (with the default cube) but the problem is that the plane is also a rigid body (passive) and I would like the cube to interact with it. But it seems like when using `follow path` constraint, the rigid bodies do not interact with each other.

[image: Project_s]

I followed the method provided by [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62523/how-to-use-rigid-body-physics-after-following-path-constraint) and even got somewhat close to what I needed, but the problem is that I want the active rigid body to follow the path and still interact with the passive rigid body. I want the cube to follow the path till the end interacting with whatever comes in between. I am attaching my blend file here:

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by interaction in this case? Do you want to make the body rotate according to the rigid body physics while keeping it's center of mass where it would be according to the constraint?

Comment: The blend file which i uploaded shows the cube following path makes contact with the plane and obeys the rigid bodies principle but deviates from the curve path. I want the cube to follow the path till the end and yes make the body rotate according to the RBP when it touches the ground. Would really appreciate if anyone could help.